# Entropy on payload

Tags: encryption, entropy, packet, obfuscation

How can I guess if a payload is obfuscated or encrypted? in other words can I apply Shannon Entropy algorithm to a binary payload?

any advice will be appreciated,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Shannon's entropy equation](http://www.bearcave.com/misl/misl_tech/wavelets/compression/shannon.html) is the standard method of calculation. Here is a simple implementation in Python, shamelessly copied from the [Revelation](http://freshmeat.net/projects/revelation/) codebase:

```
def entropy(string):
        "Calculates the Shannon entropy of a string"

        # get probability of chars in string
        prob = [ float(string.count(c)) / len(string) for c in dict.fromkeys(list(string)) ]

        # calculate the entropy
        entropy = - sum([ p * math.log(p) / math.log(2.0) for p in prob ])

        return entropy


def entropy_ideal(length):
        "Calculates the ideal Shannon entropy of a string with given length"

        prob = 1.0 / length

        return -1.0 * length * prob * math.log(prob) / math.log(2.0)
```

Note that this implementation assumes that your input bit-stream is best represented as bytes. This may or may not be the case for your problem domain.